# Multiple versions of Libcurl?

Tags: libraries, curl

Is it possible to have multiple versions of libcurl installed in Ubuntu?

For instance, suppose I have version 1.0 installed, and I download version 1.1, and install it. Is there anyway to keep version 1, and have several applications use version 1?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how upstream works, how you isntall the new version, and what you're trying to do with it, but looking at how libcurl installs certain files, the basic answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple version if the ABI changes enough. ie if the so version is bumped enough.

a good example of this is libjpeg8 vs libjpeg62

libjpeg8 is actually provided by libjpeg-turbo8.

```
dpkg --listfiles libjpeg-turbo8 | grep so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
```

libjpeg62 is provided by libjpeg62

```
dpkg --listfiles libjpeg62 | grep so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
```

this is not the best example because it was the only one I could think of at the time. due to the 8 using turbo, just try to overlook that for now.

either way 62 is not compatible with 8 hense the difference in so names.

so it is possible to have different version, but its generally only needed when there is a major ABI change.

In your example 1.1 vs 1 is not that big, and more then likely it would be binary compatible. There is a set rule to this though, maybe someone else can add more details that understands it better.